# UINavigationController not showing up when running build

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

EDIT: Working, see code below.

Working on an application, where right now I have the `AppDelegate` class, and a custom `UINavigationController` class. The code i have right now is pretty simple, and I feel like I've setup the `XIB` correctly. The build succeeds with no errors. But when the app launches, the navigationcontroller isnt displayed. I do not see the nav bar nor the table view. All I see is a blank screen. Here's the bulk of my code:

```
//
//  FTPPhotosAppDelegate.h
//  FTPPhotos
//
//  Created by Aaron McLeod on 11-05-30.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface FTPPhotosAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    RootViewController *rootViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) RootViewController *rootViewController;

@end


//
//  FTPPhotosAppDelegate.m
//  FTPPhotos
//
//  Created by Aaron McLeod on 11-05-30.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FTPPhotosAppDelegate.h"

@implementation FTPPhotosAppDelegate


@synthesize window=_window;

    @synthesize navigationController, rootViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:NO];
    [self.window addSubview:[self.navigationController view]];    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}


@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *photos;
    UIImagePickerController *picker;
    UIBarButtonItem *addPhotoButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *photos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *picker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *addPhotoButton;

- (void) loadPhotos;
- (IBAction) addPhoto;
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
@end


#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize photos, picker, addPhotoButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:50];
    [self loadPhotos];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Any ideas? Here's a screenshot of the `XIB`,

[image: http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/189/nib.png].

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Can you post an image of the NIB file with it's object hierarchy listing on the left?

Comment: Done: http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/189/nib.png I'll add to the post as well.

Comment: Please post an image with the connections of your outlets.

Comment: That's odd. I can get to it fine even in another browser where im not logged in.

Comment: It would've helped if you had expanded the left side bar. Can you also show the delegate connections ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a root View controller, make it a `UINavigationController *navigationController`.

then in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, say

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
FirstViewController *firstView = [FirstViewController alloc]init];
[self pushViewController:firstView animated:NO];
firstView.title = @"TITLE";
[self addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

EDIT: some example code i have in an app of mine

`AppDelegate.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DragonAge2AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end
```

`AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
TitleClass *titlePage = [[TitleClass alloc]init];

navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
titlePage.title = @"Dragon Age 2";
[navigationController pushViewController:titlePage animated:NO];
[titlePage release];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: Where's the FirstViewController come from? And im not sure if i understand the switch to a UINavigation controller when I'm using the IBoutlet to map it on the XIB.

Comment: FirstViewController is whatever controller you wanted to display when the app first loads. I guess in your case it would be called RootViewController. Basically what im suggesting is to push the table you are trying to display as a view as soon as the application loads. instead of a custom class. keeps things simple.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I kept my instance of RootViewController on the XIB, so it's easier to manage from a visual perspective. If you think its worth while to do it without the XIB for a learning experience, I'll give it a shot. I initialized the navigation controller and got that working. However, when I try to push the rootViewController object, it throws a SIG ABORT there.

Comment: maybe post your error log & update code? and in my opinion programatically is the way to go

Comment: Looks like I have it working. The pushViewController didnt like the fact I was pushing a subclass of a navigation controller, which makes sense. So i changed it to be a UITableViewController, and it's working fine. I'll update my code.

Comment: so everything is working fine now? if not let me know and we'll try to find another way

Comment: Yep everything is working fine. Just working on adding more to the application now. I selected your answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check some points:

- Is the code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` executed when you run the application? Add a `NSLog(@"app launched")` in this code or set a breakpoint in it to check it. If it is not called, your `FTPPhotosAppDelegate` object is probably not set as the delegate of your `UIApplication` singleton in the `XIB` (this connection should be done by default if you created your app using a standard template, but it's worth checking)
- Is the `navigationController` `IBOutlet` of your AppDelegate properly connected to your actual `UINavigationController` in the `XIB`? Check (using an `NSLog` or a breakpoint) that it is not `nil`.
- Same for the view `IBOutlet` of the `UINavigationController` object in your `XIB`: check that it is properly connected and not `nil`.

Comment: It looks like the Photos App Delegate object in the XIB was missing the connection to Files Owner. When i made the connection and rebuilt, it now crashes with a BAD_ACCESS exception in the main method.    `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`